# How do I run a job in the foreground with the at command on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, command-line, mac

I figured out [how to enable the atrun daemon on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740563/how-to-use-command-at-to-execute-shell-in-macos) so that I can use the *at* command.  However, any job I schedule seems to be run in the background.  For example, if I schedule `echo "testing"`, the output is sent to my system mail and not displayed on my terminal like I want.  Is there an option I'm not using?  I didn't see anything about this on the man page.